# Create a Asp MVC MapRoute that routes to partial named controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I want to create a MapRoute that will take the {controller} URL segment and treat it as a prefix to a controller name, something like the following…

1. Context.MapRoute would be something like “AreaName/Widgets/{action}/{id}/{controller}

   Couple URL examples: “AreaName/Widgets/Index/1234/North” and “AreaName/Widgets/Index/1234/South”

   The URLs would execute against a controllers called NorthWidgetsController and SouthWidgetsController.

Thanks in advance.